# Every value in Column 1 Needs every other value in Column 1 as a new row

Tags: mysql, join, aggregate

I am stuck on some code. As shown in the image, I need each state to be given a new row for every other road project in the country. Ohio, for example, is given 2 new rows in the new table, 1 for each other road project in the U.S (Florida's road and New York's road)...

I think this is an occasion for an aggregate function but I am new to them.

| Country | State | Road Project |
| --- | --- | --- |
| U.S. | Ohio | Highway 2 |
| U.S. | New York | Highway 3 |
| U.S. | Florida | Highway 4 |
| Canada | Ontario | Highway 82 |
| Canada | Quebeca | Highway 80 |
| Canada | Alberta | Highway 68 |

Desired Table:

| ConnectionID | State | Road_Connection |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ohio | Highway 3 |
| 2 | Ohio | Highway 4 |
| 3 | New York | Highway 2 |
| 4 | New York | Highway 4 |
| 5 | Florida | Highway 3 |
| 6 | Florida | Highway 2 |
| 7 | Ontario | Highway 80 |
| 8 | Ontario | Highway 68 |
| 9 | Quebec | Highway 68 |
| 10 | Quebec | Highway 82 |
| 11 | Alberta | Highway 80 |
| 12 | Alberta | Highway 82 |

I began with something like this, but Concat does somewhat the opposite of what I want. It turns multiple rows into one row, whereas I want the first table to expand into more rows:

````
```SELECT
    SourceTable.State,
    Group_Concat(NewTable.Road_Project, ', ') AS Road_Connections
FROM
    SourceTable

LEFT JOIN NewTable ON SourceTable.State = NewTable.State```
````

Comment: I added tables using stack exchange's format, is that sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
SELECT
     st.Country,
     st.State,
     st2.[Road Project]
FROM dbo.SourceTable AS st
     JOIN dbo.SourceTable AS st2 ON st2.Country = st.Country
                                    AND st.[Road Project] <> st2.[Road Project];
```

Comment: That did the trick, thank you Peter. Astoundingly simple-- having my head in multiple tables for weeks caused me to lose perspective and get confused!